# How to add new https certificate on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

I have problem in adding new SSL certificate on Heroku.
my app on Ruby on Rails.
I have entrust.crt,root.txt and chain.txt file

I have following problem.

heroku certs:add public.pem private.key -a myapp
Resolving trust chain... failed
 !    No key found that signs the certificate.

heroku certs:add public.pem private.key -a myapp --bypass 
Adding SSL Endpoint to myapp... failed
 !    Key doesn't match the PEM certificate

Please help me to generate PEM certificate

I follow https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint but not able to configure please help me to configure.

please give me steps to follow to configure.

entrustcert.crt

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

L1Cchain.txt

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

L1Croot.txt

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you did not include the signing certificate chain properly in your `public.pem` certificate.  This certificate must contain your host SSL certificate, and a full chain of certificates back to the root certificate.

If you have the certificate and the certificate authorization chain, you must combine these into a single `heroku.pem` certificate file like so:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
(Your Primary SSL certificate: your_domain_name.crt) 
-----END CERTIFICATE----- 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
(Your Intermediate certificate: DigiCertCA.crt) 
-----END CERTIFICATE----- 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
(Your Root certificate: TrustedRoot.crt) 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

You will need to combine these certificate entries in the single file, in the exact order above.

In your case, that should be:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
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 v5n8NJb/TkW5JdEE8x6MEvagq6+ichlB2nYOcfJKK5xsMRqokssZ9y6YOhrjzn/5OwQPuBnCvSk=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE9TCCA92gAwIBAgIETA6MOTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBtDEUMBIGA1UEChMLRW50cnVzdC5uZXQxQDA+BgNVBAsUN3d3dy5lbnRydXN0Lm5ldC9DUFNfMjA0OCBpbmNvcnAuIGJ5IHJlZi4gKGxpbWl0cyBsaWFiLikxJTAjBgNVBAsTHChjKSAxOTk5IEVudHJ1c3QubmV0IExpbWl0ZWQxMzAxBgNVBAMTKkVudHJ1c3QubmV0IENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5ICgyMDQ4KTAeFw0xMTExMTExNTQwNDBaFw0yMTExMTIwMjUxMTdaMIGxMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEWMBQGA1UEChMNRW50cnVzdCwgSW5jLjE5MDcGA1UECxMwd3d3LmVudHJ1c3QubmV0L3JwYSBpcyBpbmNvcnBvcmF0ZWQgYnkgcmVmZXJlbmNlMR8wHQYDVQQLExYoYykgMjAwOSBFbnRydXN0LCBJbmMuMS4wLAYDVQQDEyVFbnRydXN0IENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5IC0gTDFDMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAl6MtPJ7eBdoTwhGNnY7jf8dLflqfs/9iq3PIKGu6EGSChxPNVxj/KM7A5g4GkVApg9Hywyrb2NtOBMwA64u2lty8qvpSdwTB2xnkrpz9PIsD7028GgNl+cGxP3KG8jiqGa4QiHgo2nXDPQKCApy5wWV3diRMmPdtMTj72/7bNwJ2oRiXpszeIAlJNiRpQvbkN2LxWW2pPO00nKOO29w61/cKb+8u2NWTWnrtCElo4kHjWpDBhlX8UUOd4LLEZ7TLMjEl8FSfS9Fv29Td/K9ebHiQld7KOki5eTybGdZ1BaD5iNfB6KUJ5BoV3IcjqrJ1jGMlh9j4PabCzGb/pWZoVQIDAQABo4IBDjCCAQowDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgEGMBIGA1UdEwEB/wQIMAYBAf8CAQAwMwYIKwYBBQUHAQEEJzAlMCMGCCsGAQUFBzABhhdodHRwOi8vb2NzcC5lbnRydXN0Lm5ldDAyBgNVHR8EKzApMCegJaAjhiFodHRwOi8vY3JsLmVudHJ1c3QubmV0LzIwNDhjYS5jcmwwOwYDVR0gBDQwMjAwBgRVHSAAMCgwJgYIKwYBBQUHAgEWGmh0dHA6Ly93d3cuZW50cnVzdC5uZXQvcnBhMB0GA1UdDgQWBBQe8auJBvhJDwEzd+4Ueu4ZfJMoTTAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBRV5IHREYC+2Im5CKMx+aEkCRa5cDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOCAQEAQJqHfojUzCanS/p4SiDV+aI2IbvuW6BPRI3PqvmXF5aEqchnm7vmEN551lZqpHgUSdl87TBeaeptJEZaiDQ9JifPaUGEHATaGTgu24lBOX5lH51aOszhDEw3oc5gk6i1jMo/uitdTBuBiXrKNjCc/4Tj/jrx93lxybXTMwPKd86wuinSNF1z/6T98iW4NUV5eh+Xrsm+CmiEmXQ5qE56JvXN3iXiN4VlB6fKxQW3EzgNLfBtGc7emWEn7kVuxzn/9sWL4Mt8ih7VegcxKlJcOlAZOKlE+jyoz+95nWrZ5S6hjyko1+yqwfsm5p9GJKaxB825DOgNghYAHZaS/KYIoA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
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
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

If you're having trouble with the formatting, here is a gist of the file contents: https://gist.github.com/wpeterson/3220e0be105a3cbe4eef

Comment: i create server.key file using  openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.pass.key 2048 openssl rsa -in server.pass.key -out server.key  and generate heroku.pem file as your describe order still this error comes heroku certs:add heroku.pem server.key -a energystorageexchange --bypass
Adding SSL Endpoint to energystorageexchange... failed
 !    Key doesn't match the PEM certificate

Comment: You have generated a private key (`server.key`), but not a certificate.  An SSL certificate must be issued by a Certificate Authority.  Your DNS provider likely sells them.  When you are issued an SSL certificate, you will get the cert, the key, and the chain of signing certs to a root.

Comment: i have entrust SSL certificate its provide me entrustcert.crt L1Cchain.txt and L1Croot.txt

Comment: hi i create server.key on my local machine not on heroku its ok

Comment: Your SSL key should always be secret, but your SSL cert and signing chain certs will be public.  If you post your SSL cert and signing keychains in your original question, I can combine them together into a proper heroku.pem certificate with signing chain.

Comment: i added my three SSL file which provided by entrust

Comment: Added formatted pem file.  Ensure that you provide heroku with the private key used to request the certificate.

Comment: now its give me below error C:\tools\heroku>heroku certs:add heroku.pem server.key -a energystorageexchange
Resolving trust chain... failed
 !    Heroku client internal error.
    Command:     heroku certs:add heroku.pem server.key -a energystorageexchange
    Plugins:     heroku-accounts
    Version:     heroku/toolbelt/3.4.1 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it turned out I was downloading an old cert from Comodo.  When I downloaded the correct cert it worked fine.

Also, I was able to use this command to include all the intermediary certs and not have to combine them into 1 file:

```
heroku certs:update *.crt server.key -a my-app
```